# How I can create parent child relation from flat json?

Tags: javascript

I want to data in hierarchy format. Currently I took data from database with join and the format of the data is as below.

```
[{id:1, name:'India', parentId : ''},
 {id:2, name:'Gujarat', parentId : '1'},
 {id:3, name:'Ahmedabad', parentId : '2'},
 {id:4, name:'Maharastra', parentId : '1'}]
```

I want following format to bind treeview and angularjs.

```
    [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'India',
    child: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Gujarat',
        child: [
          {
            id: 3,
            name: 'Ahmedabad',
            child: [

            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Maharastra',
        child: [

        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: can you tell us what you've tried ?

Comment: I can do it with loop. But there is "map" keyword in javascript. I used it before but currently I have been forgot it. @jonatjano if you have any link shared on stackoverflow please share here.

Comment: I think you are asking wrong question because if id=4 is child of india means id=1 then it must be child of id=1 (india) in output,Please check question output

Comment: Yes correct.  It should be on level of Gujarat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it using [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/reduce)

but since you'll add object to other you need to ensure the parent was already add, so you'll need to [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/sort) first

```js
let places = [{id:1, name:'India', parentId : ''},
  {id:2, name:'Gujarat', parentId : '1'},
  {id:3, name:'Ahmedabad', parentId : '2'},
  {id:4, name:'Maharastra', parentId : '1'}]

// sort to ensure you take care of parents befose children
places = places.sort((i, j) => i.parentId - j.parentId)

let result = []

// you reduce the array
// the accumulator is used to keep easy access to object already processed
places.reduce((acc, place) => {
  // create the new object
  let plc = {id: place.id, name: place.name, childs: []}

  // if there is a parent
  if (place.parentId) {
    // add the current object to the parent
    acc[place.parentId].childs.push(plc)
  } else {
    // or add the current object to the root
    result.push(plc)
  }
  // easy acces to this object
  acc[place.id] = plc
  
  return acc
}, [])

console.log(result)
```